# covert python code encrypt to php code encrypt

Tags: php, python

I have python code which can encrypt. I want to convert it into PHP code and this is my python code:

```
hmac_signature = hmac.new("111", "222", hashlib.sha256).digest()
hmac_signature_encoded = base64.b64encode(hmac_signature)
print hmac_signature_encoded
```

Comment: What's your **specific** question?

Comment: I want convert that code from python code to php code.

Comment: That is neither a question nor specific.

Comment: stack overflow **is not** a code translation service. **try something yourself**, then ask questions about specific problems you encounter while doing so. also, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic to improve the quality of your next question.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-converting service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to explain what you have tried already to convert this code from `Python` to `PHP` so you can use google to search for "hmac.new php" and this will lead you to answers better than asking for how to write it in here as StackOverflow is not a coding service.

The following URL could be an answer to your question:

[PHP vs Python: Generating a HMAC](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2017/08/02/php-vs-python-generating-a-hmac/)

Comment: sorry, i dont know the rules. but thankyou, this really helped me.